# How can I change the Color of an Listview Item in Delphi(Firemonkey Android)

Tags: android, delphi, listview, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

How can I change the background color of a ListView Item in Firemonkey (Delphi Android)? 
The Listview itself can be set to transparent, but if I add an Item it has white background/

Answer (score 1):

I Think you'll need to do this in the style designer

Right Click on the TListView control and select "Edit Custom Style". In the Style "Structure" Treeview select the itembackground property and set the color to Null.

Remember to select the newly created ListViewStyle in the TListView's property inspector StyleLookup parameter

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try to add a TImage component as the background of your items. Then load a bitmap in it with the correct size and color.